# CGI download image after generating

Tags: python, cgi

I have a small python cgi script that accepts an image upload from the user, converts in into a different format, and saves the new file in a temp location.  I would like it to then automatically prompt the user to download the converted file.  I have tried:

```
# image conversion stuff....
print "Content-Type: image/eps\n" #have also tried application/postscript, and application/eps
print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=%s\n" % new_filename #have tried with and without this...
print open(converted_file_fullpath).read()
print
```

I have also tried:

```
print "Location: /path/to/tmp/location/%s" % new_filename
print
```

My browser either downloads `script.cgi` or `script.cgi.ps`.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When your browser downloads to the wrong filename, what data is in the file?  Is it the data you expect?

Comment: yea, when it downloads script.cgi, file looks like a postscript file.  When it downloads as script.cgi.ps, I get the correct image, but having it download with the "wrong" filename just bothers me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but have you tried separating actual data from headers by newline? EDIT: writing `print "\n"` outputs two newlines, so I think it should be written like that:

```
print "Content-Type: image/eps"
print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=%s" % new_filename
print
print open(converted_file_fullpath).read()
```

Assuming that `new_filename` has some reasonable value I can't see what is wrong here.

Comment: Even with '\n' removed from prints? Is there any output (print statements) before `print "Content-Type: image/eps"`?

Comment: bingo, didn't notice that you took `\n` out of the prints...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, you can use the `Location` header for this, but it only worked for me with an absolute link.  So,

```
print 'Location: http://example.com/path/to/tmp/location/%s' % new_filename
print
```

I know, the cgi spec says that relative links should work for internal redirects, but this is what worked for me...