# Trouble getting browser to download from python cgi script

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, download, cgi

I am attempting to download a .JSON to the client-side machine for backup purposes. Right now the way I am doing this is through a cgi script being called by a JQuery POST request. I followed the guide [at the bottom of this page](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm) about raising a "File Download..." box, as well as information from [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215623/cgi-download-image-after-generating) accepted answer.

At the moment, the script runs, and returns the JSON correctly, but the browser does not automatically download it, nor does it raise the "file download" box as I expected it to.

Here are my headers and print statements from the script:

```
print "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name='testfile.json'"
print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='testfile.json'\n"
print json.dumps(configJSON)
```

I am not sure if I formatted the above incorrectly, or whether I have to add something to my request in order for it to download the response. My request is currently as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'cgi-bin/sendConfig.py',
})
```

As I said above, I could see perhaps needing to add a `.done()` function to the request, but the way the article linked above is written, it seems as though the Content-Type and Content-Disposition settings should automatically start the download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript by design cannot access the filesystem, so cant initiate a file download via ajax.

If you visit that url ( cgi-bin/sendConfig.py ) directly with your browser you will get the download prompt.

If you need to initiate this download via javascript, you can try a couple of options.
You can redirect to the page :

```
window.location.href = "http://yoursite.com/cgi-bin/sendConfig.py";
```

or add an invisable iframe to the page:

```
$('body').append('<iframe src="http://yoursite.com/cgi-bin/sendConfig.py" style="display:none;"></iframe>');
```

Comment: Wow thanks! You know, I had read that, as you said "Javascript by design cannot access the filesystem" earlier when I was looking into this, but somehow I didn't put that together in my head that it meant I wouldn't be able to use AJAX to accomplish this.

There seems to be a new potential problem though. The script seems to work, the file seems to be downloaded in its entirety, but Chrome shows the script as being "canceled" in the network tab. Also, I had expected a "download as..." sort of window, but the file downloaded automatically instead. That might just be Chrome though.

Comment: Chrome doesnt show a download as box, but the cancelled thing is odd. You may need to adjust your headers, maybe: 'Content-Type: application/json'